# Java date conversion from EST to UTC

Tags: java, timezone

I am working under an application API (DFC) that is giving me a Date-like object (IDfTime). The API automatically converts date to local time zone (EST). I need to convert to UTC to send to oracle database. For some reason, my code is adding a month. I don't understand it. Can anyone explain this?

`modifyDate` is the Date-like object that is returned by app API. I have converted it to string and it looks like expected (EST for me). So, using Calendar and SimpleDateFormat to convert it to specific-formatted string that I can send to database with UTC string in SQL update statement.

Note: I am writing debug statements to a batch job log file that gets generated by the app instead of stdout. Yes, there are better ways but this was supposed to be a quick widget.

```
//adjust modify date for UTC to send to database
String dfcDatePattern = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss";
String javaDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
String oracleDatePattern = "MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS";

String strModifyDate = modifyDate.asString(dfcDatePattern);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Modify Date String: " + strModifyDate + NEWLINE);

TimeZone localTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
TimeZone utcTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeZone(localTimeZone);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Year: " + modifyDate.getYear() + NEWLINE);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Month: " + modifyDate.getMonth() + NEWLINE);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Day: " + modifyDate.getDay() + NEWLINE);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Hour: " + modifyDate.getHour() + NEWLINE);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Minutes: " + modifyDate.getMinutes() + NEWLINE);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("DFC Seconds: " + modifyDate.getSeconds() + NEWLINE);
cal.set(modifyDate.getYear(), modifyDate.getMonth(), modifyDate.getDay(), modifyDate.getHour(), modifyDate.getMinutes(), modifyDate.getSeconds());
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("Converted Modify Date: " + cal.toString() + NEWLINE);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(javaDatePattern);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("Modify Date in Local Time Zone: " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + NEWLINE);
sdf.setTimeZone(utcTimeZone);
if (m_debugMode) m_File.writeBytes("Modify Date in UTC Time Zone: " + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + NEWLINE);

updateQueryString = "execute exec_sql with query = 'update dm_sysobject_s set r_modify_date = TO_DATE(''" + sdf.format(cal.getTime())  + "'',''" + oracleDatePattern + "'') where r_object_id = ''" + objectIdString + "'' '";
```

Output:

```
DFC Modify Date String: 03/30/2016 11:44:30 [yep, looks good]
DFC Year: 2016
DFC Month: 3   [month looks good here]
DFC Day: 30
DFC Hour: 11   [EST hour]
DFC Minutes: 44
DFC Seconds: 30
```

[yep each part looks good]

```
Converted Modify Date: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=14,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=30,DAY_OF_YEAR=90,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=44,SECOND=30,MILLISECOND=399,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

[Dumped this to see if I could figure out what is going on. I think that all looks good]

```
Modify Date in Local Time Zone: 04/30/2016 11:44:30
```

[not good! time is correct, but it added a month!? UTC offset is only 4 hours!]

```
Modify Date in UTC Time Zone: 04/30/2016 15:44:30
```

[not good! time was correctly adjusted as expected, but still added a month]

```
exec_sql to update r_modify_date: execute exec_sql with query = 'update dm_sysobject_s set r_modify_date = TO_DATE(''04/30/2016 15:44:30'',''MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'') where r_object_id = ''09ae12f980002934'' '
```

[this is what I want the SQL to look like; same day, but time adjusted for UTC offset. but the month is off. the SQL syntax is good (looks strange due to API syntax); it updates the record in DB; just with wrong month.]

I suppose I could just brute force a hard-coded offset by adding four hours, but I think the above is the "correct" way. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I believe Month is zero-based for java.util.GregorianCalendar, so 3 is April, rather than March

Comment: OMG. I didn't think of that. Confirmed in javadoc: The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0. Thank you so much; was pulling my hair out.

Comment: Also, I salute your effort to handle timezone programmatically rather than by brute force. In my experience it's a hassle that usually pays off.

Answer (score 0):

In java.util.GregorianCalendar, Month is zero based.  To indicate March, you should pass 2 rather than 3.

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=14,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=30,DAY_OF_YEAR=90,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=44,SECOND=30,MILLISECOND=399,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```